# How do I install Xorg with a dummy video driver and run it if I don't have root rights?

Tags: xorg

I have a console-only machine I don't have root rights on. I need to install and run Xorg there. The machine uses Ubuntu 20.04 LTS if it matters. (probably not)

Comment: Someone has given you access to a server with no desktop environment?  They probably don't want you installing Xorg... Contact the system administrator

Comment: OK, I managed to solve the problem using rootless podman. Still looking for a solution without containers though.